# How to find the same data in colume and fill color to show them?

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in column and the data has the same group so I want to fill color to show them but it has many group. I don't know how to change the color.

I try to use `If then else` and `array` but I can't do that.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim bottomA As Integer
    bottomA = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each c In Range("A3:A" & bottomA)
        If c = c.Offset(1, 0) Or c = c.Offset(-1, 0) Then
           c.Interior.Color = 255
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

It has the same color and I think it doesn't suit for my work because it considers cell by cell not by group to fill the color.

[image: This picture will show you when my code run]

[this is what i want to create code to run that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf6tq.jpg)
If there are the same value they will have the same color and that color will not use again
If the value is unique that range won’t fill the color

Comment: Are you trying to shade duplicates? If so, why not use conditional formatting?

Comment: Because data will change everyday. In 1 day some data will have the same group but it don’t similar group with other days.

Comment: Doesn’t matter just use a COUNTIF.

Comment: Can you explain about that?

Comment: I hadn't noticed it's actually a built-in feature  https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/find-duplicates.html

Comment: Scratch that. Are you only wanting to shade a cell if the cell above and below is the same? What's the problem with the answer below?

Comment: I will try that one if i have some problem i will ask you

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Color` property and the `RGB` function.

```
Range("A1").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

**Explanation**:

RGB stands for Red, Green and Blue. These are the three primary colors. Each component can take on a value from 0 to 255. With this function you can make every color.

RGB(255,0,0) gives the pure `Red` color.

**Edit1:** 
`Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown)` returns you the range from cell a3 to the cell at the end of the region.

If you want to compare the values of ranges, you should to change the

`c = c.Offset(1, 0) Or c = c.Offset(-1, 0)`

to

`c.Value = c.Offset(1, 0).Value Or c.Value = c.Offset(-1, 0).Value`

The full VBA code:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown))
        If c = c.Offset(1, 0) Or c = c.Offset(-1, 0) Then
           c.Interior.Color = 255
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice but if i do that column “A” will have red if i put instead of the code after “then”.

Comment: I’m so sorry.  I accidentally press.

Comment: I don't understand, what do you want by `If c = c.Offset(1, 0) Or c = c.Offset(-1, 0) Then`. Can you make it clear?

Comment: Yes,it help me but i will explain about that I did that code example focus on “200035317” and  if i use “if c=c.offset(1,0)) then” the last “20035317” won’t be fill the color that why I use that code. I will post what i want to show.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand you. You want to fill up the cells of the row by different color depending by value of cell?